# HTML won't load image from another directory

Tags: html

I'm learning HTML and I'm just starting to learn about an image manipulation. The image I want to use is in different directory of the document and I've tried to load it in my document. The directory of Html document is **MY/COMPUTER/PATH/Desktop/Code/Images.html**  and the directory of an image is **MY/COMPUTER/PATH/Downloads/Image.jpg** and the code is that follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <body>
          <img src="../../Downloads/Image.jpg" alt ="This is an image that should 
          work">
     </body>
</html>
```

I would like to get some help from other people. Thanks.

Comment: How did you serve this HTML file? Through a web server? Or what? Give detail about your environment and steps to reproduce the problem. Are you sure the image is valid? What do you mean by "won't work" and "won't load"? What does the console say?

Comment: In your case the correct relative path should be `../../Downloads/Image.jpg` but that's what you are writing so it's not a path problem, maybe the image have another extension, and you need to tell how are you serving that html file.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm using localhost to execute the code and TextEdit to edit it. The image is valid (I use it without issue later in the code.) When I say "won't work" and "won't load" I mean that instead of the image, the alt text appears, meaning that there's an issue with retrieving the image.

Comment: What do you mean by "using localhost"? Is it a webserver? Or are you just double-clicking the HTML file locally so it opens as a local file in your browser? _"I use it without issue later in the code."_ That's an important detail! What's the difference between where you use it and fail, and where you use it and succeed? You did not show any of this in your question.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings later in my code I access the image from within the same directory as my code, so I know the extension is .jpg and not .jpeg, .png, etc. This also means that the image is a valid image. Localhost is a local web server accessed from within your computer's terminal and loads on a certain port and is accessed on your web browser. It accesses the code then executes it in the browser (e.g. http://localhost:8080/image.html loads the .html file image.html and executes the code using port 8080 to compute it.)

Comment: @Atat So, you're using a web server. Is this webpage at the root? You can't "escape" the root. Imagine if you could! Any web author could access any file on the webserver's host computer... You told your webserver (via a config file) which folder your website is in. Then a part of your website tried to access files outside of that folder. That cannot work. Which webserver are you using? Which guide/documentation are you following?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I was using https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp to learn about file paths and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML to learn about image and image formatting in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It's a best practice to maintain the proper directory structure.

Here is the basic directory structure which you should follow, it will help you to gather all assets in the same place

```
>projectName
    >assets
        >images
        >css
        >js
    >index.html
```

Comment: I know that I should do that, but this is just a thing that I'm doing to know how to. In the future I don't plan on using the "../" method.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <body>
          <img src="assets/images/image.jpg"
               alt = "This is an image that should work"
          >
     </body>
</html>
```

```
>projectName
    >assets
        >images
        >css
        >js
    >index.html
    >about.html
    >contact.html
```